# Proving that $\lim \limits_{b \rightarrow \infty} F(a,b,\frac{1}{2};\frac{z^2}{4ab})=\cosh z$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to prove that $\lim \limits_{a,b \rightarrow \infty} F(a,b,\frac{1}{2};\frac{z^2}{4ab})=\cosh z$ . Here $F$
 is the hypergeometric function.

Here because of two limits I am unable to understand how to go about it. I am able to prove it formally i.e. by taking limit inside but to justify I do not know how to begin. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

We have:

$$\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(a,b;\frac{1}{2};\frac{z^2}{4ab}\right) = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(a)_k (b)_k}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k k!}\left(\frac{z^2}{4ab}\right)^k =\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(a)_k (b)_k}{a^k b^k (2k)!}z^{2k}$$
and since for any fixed $k$ we have:
$$ \lim_{a,b\to +\infty}\frac{(a)_k (b)_k}{a^k b^k} = 1$$
it follows that:
$$ \lim_{a,b\to +\infty}\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(a,b;\frac{1}{2};\frac{z^2}{4ab}\right) =\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}=\cosh z$$
as wanted.

Comment: How do we justify taking the limit inside?